# socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known when assigning a variable instead of static address to sendto() function

Tags: python

I am struggling with this error since 2 days now and no matter how much I googled, there is no answer for my problem!
I'm writing a network program in python. On sender side I have a raspberri pi. What it does is that it receives a data from an ipv6 node, sends it over lora to another raspberry pi node which after receiving this data sends an acknowledgment to the initial node. I send the IP of the initial sender node along with the data, so the end node can send the ack only to the initial sender. But when I try to send the ack through my socket.sendto in my python program in the first raspberry pi, I get the error:

```
s.sendto(data,(ip,5555))
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

If I assign a static address to the receiver in sendto function like the bellow code, everything works like a charm. But when I try to read the address from the data that was sent and use that variable as an IP address I get the said error.

```
 s.sendto(data,("ff02::2",5555))
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried it using both python 2.7 and 3.4 and the problem stands in both.

Answer (score 0):

I've also found this issue and while not solved, it probably relates to the fact the setup requires a tuple (an imutable pair) as the address/port info. As such a variable inside it is unlikely to work.

When I get a fix or answer, will repost.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually solved the issue. It seemed like the variable I was passing to sendto() function had some space character in it which (apparently) caused the error. When I limited the variable value to the IP characters only it worked :)